# Outlook 365 online, Outlook online, creating folders: View contents of subfolder in parent folder for team emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

I am super new to MS, windows and Office since I worked in Apple my whole life. here is my goal which I could do in Apple mail, thunder mail and others.

Folder My sales team.

Subfolders

Bill, jack, clark, dan, ashley and jennifer

I should be able to go to folder my sales team and see all the emails in the subfolders and then if I want to I could go to each sub folder and view only emails that the person sent to me.

This seems so simple on other programs and yet on office 365 it at turned me to drinking!.

Any help would be great.

Here is what I have tried

Tried creating a "search folder" but i dont have the option to select email addresses
Tried creating a rule for a folder but the emails only stay in 1 folder.

Comment: So what have you attempted so far? This site is not a free scripting service. We will help you debug any scripts you might have tried, but we will code a script or formula for free.

Comment: Can you show us how you set up the rules or how you tried setting up the search folder?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are saying "Outlook 365 Online" and "Outlook Online", guess you are using the Outlook on the web via https://outlook.office.com. Then you can follow the steps below for your requirement:

1. Manually create the folder hierarchy on the basis of your needs. For instructions on how to create folders or subfolders in OWA, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/working-with-message-folders-in-outlook-on-the-web-ae0f10d6-54e7-4f29-acd3-78cdc3fdcb9f.
   [image]
2. [Create inbox rules](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/inbox-rules-in-outlook-web-app-edea3d17-00c9-434b-b9b7-26ee8d9f5622) for each subfolders.
   Go to Settings > Mail > Rules, add a new rule, set up the rules like below for each of the senders:
   Note: In the from condition field, you can type the full email address of the sender and then press Enter.
   [image]